# Ecore defaultValue for EByteArray or EFloat with multiplicities

Tags: java, default-value, eclipse-emf, eclipse-emf-ecore, ecore

I have a question regarding to the default values in an ecore model:

Is it possible to set a default value for an attribute of type `EByteArray` (with upper and lower bound = 3) or for an attribute of type `EFloat` (with upper and lower bound = 3)?

When I try that I get only something like:

```
The default value literal ... must be a valid literal of the attribute's type.
```

Answer (score 0):

Default value literal for byte arrays is a string in Hex (like ffffff for 3 bytes array). Default value literal for float is a string with an "f"-suffix (like 1.5f)